# PHP AES 128 Decryption returning result with garbage in front

Tags: php, encryption

I use the following PHP code to decrypt my AES 128 string.

```
function aes128_cbc_encrypt($key, $data, $iv) {
  if(16 !== strlen($key)) $key = hash('MD5', $key, true);
  if(16 !== strlen($iv)) $iv = hash('MD5', $iv, true);
  $padding = 16 - (strlen($data) % 16);
  $data .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);
  return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
}

$password = "mypasswordonthefirstrunoftheprogram";
$salt = "mysalthereitisfinallyitturnedoutok";
$encrypted = "BxGi119ltnYVNikXSP8jMJtSNIDKoMsPfd/nUEwlgSviVRM50/UgMF36j6Cqe+I/";


echo aes128_cbc_decrypt($key, $encrypted, $iv);
```

RIGHT RESULT =
 this is my test sentence

RESULT RETURNED =
 º±h©MM®StOfthis is my test sentenceok

Furthermore I decoded the string in C# with the right key and IV succesfully, so there is no error in that.

I wonder how this come ? I did the right padding and also tried the some other methods in php but all returning garbage in front of the right answer.

Comment: Please do not make passwords decryptable.

Comment: The password is not decryptable, i generate an iv and key from it and put it here to display for information.

Comment: The question is why the garbage occurs ?

Comment: maybe interesting? [If You're Typing the Word MCRYPT Into Your PHP Code, You're Doing It Wrong](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong). Also: [Everyone should have stopped using the PHP Mcrypt extension for new work already](http://thefsb.tumblr.com/post/110749271235/using-opensslendecrypt-in-php-instead-of).

Comment: Yup, did you found a solution ?

Comment: It depends on what `aes128_cbc_decrypt` does. Please include its code. We're not here to guess.

Comment: return mcrypt_decrypt($this->mcrypt_cipher, $key, base64_decode($encrypted), $this->mcrypt_mode, $iv);

Comment: `mcrypt_decrypt` is not removing the padding.

Answer (score 0):

`$encrypted` length is not correct for encrypting `"this is my test sentence"`.

The plain text is 26 characters
The padding would be 6-bytes
The string encrypted would be 32-bytes
The encrypted data would be  32-bytes
The Base64 encrypted data would be 44-bytes

The provided Base64 encrypted data is be 64-bytes
The provided encrypted data is be 48-bytes
There are an extra 16 bytes in the encrypted data

Examing the encrypted data there are an additional 16 bytes prepended to the encrypted bata prior to Base64 encoding.

Additionally the padding is not being removed from the decrypted data.